# SpringBoot conflicts with Hibernate used in a dependency

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a Hibernate-based module which works fine when used in a non-SpringBoot application, integrated as a dependency in Maven.

However when trying to add the same module as a dependency to a SpringBoot application, the application fails with:

```
[2019-04-05 20:27:14.157] - 2060 WARNING [main] --- org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionAdvisor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]] for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.
[2019-04-05 20:27:14.173] - 2060 SEVERE [main] --- org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter: 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Is there a way to tell Spring Boot to just back off and let the dependency module handle its own transaction management?

Comment: It's a bit hard to find the problem without knowing your dependencies and your code, but I'd guess that you've got two Hibernate dependencies and related beans via Spring and your own module. Can't you simply get rid of Hibernate in your Spring app or rewrite your modules configuration to only produce Hibernate-related beans if not already present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been 2+ years since the original post but I recently re-encountered this problem. I spent a few more hours investigating and concluded there is still no legit solution.

My initial work-around was to defer and postpone the adoption of Spring Boot in the affected project.

Final work-around is to consolidate all uses of Hibernate through a single microservice with `spring-boot-jpa`, so that the Hibernate usage is contained within the same project, instead of being pulled in as a transient dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is auto configure, Add this code for auto configure :

@AutoConfigureBefore and @AutoConfigureAfter